# Failed Cucumber Test in Active Admin with 'create' action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cucumber, activeadmin

When I try to test create new object in cucumber tests through ActiveAdmin panel in log file I see error (below). I can create this object in development env without errors, and when I edit and update present object in test env - it's ok.

I use cucumber, active admin, devise, cancan.

```
AbstractController::ActionNotFound - The action 'create' could not be found for Admin::PermissionsController:
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:131:in `process'
  actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  cucumber-rails (1.4.0) lib/cucumber/rails/action_controller.rb:10:in `call'
  railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.0.2) lib/quiet_assets.rb:18:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/builder.rb:138:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/urlmap.rb:65:in `block in call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/urlmap.rb:50:in `call'
  capybara (2.2.1) lib/capybara/server.rb:19:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /Users/am/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/am/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/am/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Answer (score 1):

I found answer, problem was with FactoryGirl and Cucumber. In cucumber env I included FactoryGirl's methods:

```
include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
```

After, I found issue in cucumber-rails (https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-rails/issues/224) and writed to env:

```
World(FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods)
```

It's work!

Comment: It works. For me the issue was for custom sessions controller inheriting from Devise::SessionsController. Any idea why this could be causing an issue?